# Why ubuntu 13.10 always show "access prompt" when start?

Tags: upgrade, updates, 13.10

After my Ubuntu PC update from 13.04 to 13.10, when start up, an access prompt always show and ask me password for "my_email@gmail.com". I was input password for email or another services, which registed with "my_email@gmail.com", but it's still "incorect". I can close but next time, it appears again. It never appeared before 13.10. What is application show that prompt? **How can I turn off this?**

Here is access prompt?
[image]

Comment: remove online google accounts, restart and again add it.

Comment: your comment should be an Answer. Thank @shantanu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's gone. I removed all online account, restart then re-add them... The prompt never ask again